# History of the Coefficients of Elliptic Curves -- Why $a_6$?

Tags: notation, math-history, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I would like to know what is the motivation behind the naming convention of the Weierstrass form of elliptic curves given as
$$E:y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6.$$

I can see that $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ are named by sorting monomials by lex order with $x<y$. But why go from $a_5$ to $a_6$?

Comment: In confirmation of @zyx’s response, the sorting by lex order has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is from having $x$ of degree $2$, $y$ of degree $3$, and giving degree $i$ to $a_i$ so that, under this assignment of degrees, every term has  degree $6$.  Equivalently,  $a_i$ is the coefficient of the degree $6-i$ term, under the same weighting of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I see! Thanks for your answer, but why adopt this convention?

Comment: The $a_i$ are, in a suitable sense, weight $i$ generators of rings of modular forms.  Classically, over the complex numbers, $a_4$ and $a_6$ are proportional to Eisenstein series of weights $4$ and $6$.  In more general situations (see Tate's *Formulaire* written up by Deligne) the weight $n$ modular forms are certain degree $n$ polynomials in the $a_i$, again with $a_i$ having weight $i$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Alas, I have not yet gone into modular forms, but when I do, I will look out for what you have said. Thanks again!